# Make a subgroup reference (\g<1>) optional in re.sub

Tags: python, regex

How can I make a subgroup reference (`\g<1>`) optional in `re.sub()`? For example with:

```
import re

regexp = re.compile(r'^http://(lists\.|www\.)?example\.com/')
regexp.sub(
    r'https://\g<1>example.com/',
    r'http://example.com/helllo-there'
)
```

I would like `\g<1>` to be replaced with nothing, the optional subgroup isn't matched (and not raise an exception).

I know I can use `regexp.match(..).groups()` to check which groups are present, but this seems like a lot of work to me (we would need a bunch of replacement patterns, since some examples go up to `\g<6>`). It's also not very fast since we need to do a `match` *and* a `replace`.

For example in JavaScript, I can use `$1`, if it's not matched it's just ignored:

```
'http://example.com/helllo-there'.replace(
    RegExp('^http://(lists\.|www\.)?example\.com/'),
    'https://$1example.com/')
// Outputs: "https://example.com/helllo-there"
```

Comment: You throw away the result of `re.compile` and your `regexp` is not defined.

Comment: On `(lists\.|www\.)?` the matched group will be _NULL_ if not matched, whereas `((?:lists\.|www\.)?)` will be the empty string. Are you saying Python can't handle _NULL_ in string composition ? Or, is that raising the exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand correctly, just do `x(y?)z` instead of `x(y)?z`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to provide an explicit empty alternative:

```
 regexp = re.compile(r'^http://(lists\.|www\.|)example\.com/')
```

Also, you can use just `\1` instead of `\g<1>`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do like this. Just put the pattern inside a non-capturing group and make it as optional. Now include that optional non-capturing group inside a capturing group.

```
>>> re.sub(r'^http://((?:lists\.|www\.)?)example\.com/',r'https://\g<1>example.com/', 'http://example.com/helllo-there')
'https://example.com/helllo-there'
```